# Testing AngularJS directive scope undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test one of my directives and I can't work out why my scope object is undefined.

```
define(["require", "exports", 'angular', 'directives', "angularMocks", "chartApp"], function (require, exports, angular, Directives) {
    "use strict";
    describe('board controls', function () {
        describe('task filter', function () {
            var $compile;
            var $rootScope;
            var scope;
            var element;
            beforeEach(angular.mock.module('chartApp'));
            beforeEach(angular.mock.module('partials/directives/board-controls.html'));
            beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
                $compile = _$compile_;
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
                expect(scope).toBeDefined();
                element = $compile('<board-controls></board-controls>')(scope);
                scope.$digest();
            }));
            it('displays modal', function () {
                scope.showChildFilters();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

In the `it('displays modal')...` part Karma outputs:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.showChildFilters')`

But in the `beforeEach(...)` part it seems to be working. I just can't see why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to this

```
    it('displays modal', function () {
       //scope.showChildFilters();

     var isolateScope = element.isolateScope(); //I prefer to name isolateScope
     isolateScope.$apply() //cause scope to digest and watch and all that

     isolateScope.showChildFilters();
    });
```

This is a very detailed answer to your question as well.
[Testing element directive - can't access isolated scope methods during tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713909/testing-element-directive-cant-access-isolated-scope-methods-during-tests)